# Specifying a string value in the type definition for the Elixir typespecs

Tags: erlang, elixir, static-analysis, typechecking, dialyzer

Is it possible to define a type as follows:

```
defmodule Role do
  use Exnumerator, values: ["admin", "regular", "restricted"]

  @type t :: "admin" | "regular" | "restricted"

  @spec default() :: t
  def default() do
    "regular"
  end
end
```

to make a better analyze for the code like:

```
@type valid_attributes :: %{optional(:email) => String.t,
                            optional(:password) => String.t,
                            optional(:role) => Role.t}

@spec changeset(User.t, valid_attributes) :: Ecto.Changeset.t
def changeset(%User{} = user, attrs = %{}) do
  # ...
end

# ...

User.changeset(%User{}, %{role: "superadmin"}) |> Repo.insert()
```

I know that I can define this type as `@type t :: String.t`, but then, Dialyzer won't complain about using a different value than possible (possible from the application point of view).

I didn't saw any hints about this use case in the documentation for the [Typespecs](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/typespecs.html), but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: I guess that this is something with the binaries implementation, because works fine with atoms

Comment: Why would you want to use binaries in the enumeration in the first place? This is counter-idiomatic. Use atoms and `dialyzer` is all yours.

Comment: @mudasobwa because using atoms is not supported by the Ecto out of the box. As far as I understand, I need to handle casting to string manually.

Comment: Would not `<<"admin">> | ...` work? Looks like it should, according to the linked typespecs page.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I've decided to use atoms instead (the answer with code snippets below).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is not possible to use binary values in the described way. However, similar behavior can be achieved using atoms and - in my case - [a custom Ecto type](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Type.html):

```
defmodule Role do
  @behaviour Ecto.Type

  @type t :: :admin | :regular | :restricted
  @valid_binary_values ["admin", "regular", "restricter"]

  @spec default() :: t
  def default(), do: :regular

  @spec valid_values() :: list(t)
  def valid_values(), do: Enum.map(@valid_values, &String.to_existing_atom/1)

  @spec type() :: atom()
  def type(), do: :string

  @spec cast(term()) :: {:ok, atom()} | :error
  def cast(value) when is_atom(value), do: {:ok, value}
  def cast(value) when value in @valid_binary_values, do: {:ok, String.to_existing_atom(value)}
  def cast(_value), do: :error

  @spec load(String.t) :: {:ok, atom()}
  def load(value), do: {:ok, String.to_existing_atom(value)}

  @spec dump(term()) :: {:ok, String.t} | :error
  def dump(value) when is_atom(value), do: {:ok, Atom.to_string(value)}
  def dump(_), do: :error
end
```

It allows to use the following code:

```
defmodule User do
  use Ecto.Schema

  import Ecto.Changeset

  @type t :: %User{}
  @type valid_attributes :: %{optional(:email) => String.t,
                              optional(:password) => String.t,
                              optional(:role) => Role.t}

  @derive {Poison.Encoder, only: [:email, :id, :role]}
  schema "users" do
    field :email, :string
    field :password, :string, virtual: true
    field :password_hash, :string
    field :role, Role, default: Role.default()

    timestamps()
  end

  @spec changeset(User.t, valid_attributes) :: Ecto.Changeset.t
  def changeset(%User{} = user \\ %User{}, attrs = %{}) do
  # ...
end
```

This way, Dialyzer will catch an invalid user's role:

```
User.changeset(%User{}, %{role: :superadmin}) |> Repo.insert()
```

Unfortunately, it forces using atoms in place of strings in the application. It can be problematic if we already have a big code base or if we need plenty of possible values ([the limit of atoms in the system and the the fact that they are not garbage collected](http://erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/advanced.html)).

Comment: “plenty of possible values”—lol, millions? It’s a rule of thumb: for inner data we always prefer atoms over binaries.

Comment: Maybe not millions because default limit is around 1 million. That is just an information to consider ;)